# WPF full-screen app debug in "portrait" mode

Tags: wpf, zooming, landscape-portrait

I have to make a "portrait" 1080x1920 full-screen app with some fixed-size images on it, using WPF. But I have standard "landscape" 1920x1080 screen which I work on, so i can't run my app to test it. I also can't turn my screen 90 degrees (it doesn't rotate).

How it could be overcomed? Maybe some kind of "zooming tags" exist like this

```
<zoom value=50%>
   ... my xaml interface ...
</zoom>
```

I could temporarily use them during debug sessions..

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a `ViewBox` around your MainWindow's `Grid`? That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if i completely understand your problem,
but if you want to make rotation on object
you can use  object like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
       <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

and if you want to make Scaling (zoom in - out)
you can use the following tag

```
 <Grid>
       <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
       </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
```

the the value of one mean you do not want to scale at all
the values above 1 mean zooom in (enlarging)
the values below 1 mean zoom out (smalling)

Hope that is helpful

Comment: Second code works, but `Viewbox Height="1080" Width="1920"> ... </Viewbox>` seems better approach. Thank you, anyway.